# Why sometimes i get incorrect given_name and family_name

Tags: android, logging, android-contacts

I want get GIVEN_NAME and FAMILY_NAME, but sometimes i get incorrect data. Below i will give log.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
getNameStructure(cr, id);

private void getNameStructure(ContentResolver cr, String id) {

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "= ?", new String[]{id}, null);

    int indexGivenName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
    int indexFamilyName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME);
    int indexDisplayName = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String given = cursor.getString(indexGivenName);
        String family = cursor.getString(indexFamilyName);
        String display = cursor.getString(indexDisplayName);
        Log.d("Log", " given " + given + " family " + family + " display " + display);
    }

    cursor.close();

}
```

It is log example:

```
given Vg family null display Vg //correct
given Xcy family null display Xcy //correct
given 2 family null display 536-55-55 //no corrent, i don`t know what is in given and family, but display is phone, but must be name "Note test con111"
```

Comment: Test it on different devices

Comment: Most likely you have wrong data in your database. Now I can't confirm if this is the case.